# Minimizing or eliminating Cufon delayed replacement (text "flashing" or "flickering")

Tags: jquery, cufon

I'm trying the technique graham has shared on this topic (http://j.mp/cy6IRR) and I know I'm doing something super bonehead here. I'm hoping to get some help from someone that's successfully dealt with this Cufon issue. I'm seeing the flicker in all browsers it seems.

**Cufon JS Call in**

```
function initCufon() {
    Cufon.replace('#content h2', { fontFamily: 'Liquorstore'});
    Cufon.now();  
    $("#content h2").css("z-index","0");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 initCufon();
});
```

---

**CSS**

```
#content h2{
 margin:0;
 font-size:36px;
 line-height:36px;
 color:#980037;
 width:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.js #content h2{text-indent:-9999px;}
```

---

**HTML**

```
<!-- main content -->
                <div id="content">
                    <!-- content heading -->
                    <div class="main-heading">
                        <h2>Page Title</h2>
                        <script>document.documentElement.className = 'js';</script>
<!--NOTE: I forgot to add the line above in my original question post-->
```

---

P.S. I'm new to Stack Overflow and please school me if I was supposed to post this in the thread that prompted it. I'm assuming not though because it certainly ain't an "answer"!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add this line just below your `<h2>`?

> Add document.documentElement.className = 'js'; just below your tag.

Comment: Thanks for the insanely fast reply, stevelove.I just now realized that the code samples I posted above actually are working and to answer your question I do have that js just below the tag. Do you know if I need that below every element where cufon is being used? Or maybe just the big ones where it's obvious? Cufon is being used (possibly over-used) on this particular site.

Comment: `document.documentElement.className = 'js';` should result in `<html class="js">` and only needs to be on the page once. This means that your CSS of `.js #content h2` will match any `<h2>` that descends from `<div id="content">` descending from `<html class="js">`. For the goal of preventing flicker, you should probably put it in the `<head>` or just after the `<body>` tag.